# NetSuite add list responses and order of corresponding records in request

Tags: netsuite

I'm doing an add list request with multiple records getting passed to it. I need to be able to get the internal IDs of the records that get created as a result of my request. I know those come back in the write responses that get returned. However, my question is if the responses come back in the same order as the records I pass in the request. If not, then how will I know which response corresponds with which record?

Comment: 10 years later, I'm looking for documentation that affirms whether this is true or not. The one answer below doesn't really address the question

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the ID of the item in the external ID field. I don't know if the recordRef returned will return both the internal ID and external ID or not. It may. If so, you will be able to tie the external ID back to your item in the list.